# Fill in the blanks

Tags: riddle, word

Every morning starts out the same. I wake up and grab a cup of ____. I then go and feed my pet ______ a mouse or two.

If it's a weekend, I will watch a movie or read a book about my favorite mathematician ___ L. If the day is truly nice, I may go spend some time at the ____. It really just depends. One time I found a ____ buried in the sand, just glittering away.

Now, my job is pretty _____. I don't really do anything special or fun. I work in an ________ facility for display furniture.

I'm just glad I'm feeling better. I had the _____, and man was my throat sore.

---

Fill in the blanks, it might not be hard. Some of the blanks are *sound alikes*, but they all follow the same theme.

What are the missing words, and what is the theme that links them?

Comment: Ooh! Mad-libs! Can someone give me: A noun, a type of animal, a name, a place, a noun, an adjective, another adjective, and another noun.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found out the theme, here's a proper set:

> 1)**[Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language))**
>
> 2)**[Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language))**
>
> 3)**[Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language))** ([Lovelace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace))
>
> 4)**[C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language))** [[sea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea)]
>
> 5)**[Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language))**
>
> 6)**[BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC)**
>
> 7)**[Assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language)**
>
> 8)**[MUMPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS)**

Now for the real fun/challenge....Filling the blanks with what wasn't expected:

> 1)**[Elixer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elixir_(programming_language))**
>
> 2)**[Wyvern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wyvern_(programming_language))**
>
> 3)**[Mary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_(programming_language))** ([Leakey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Leakey))
>
> 4)**[Fortress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortress_(programming_language))**
>
> 5)**[Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl)**
>
> 6)**[RAPID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAPID)**
>
> 7)**[Oak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oak_(programming_language))**
>
> 8)**[Magma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(computer_algebra_system))**

Reference:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages

You can answer this yourself now with the reference provided :-)

Comment: #4: SEA, perhaps? Also, #7 is Assembly. :)

Comment: #3 is Pascal, #4 is C (sound alike)

Comment: @pacoverflow I didn't think he would break the rules for #4 :(

Comment: Note that Perl and Pearl are soundalikes as well. :)

Comment: Is the last one MUMPS?

Comment: An inappropriate, but funnier answer for #8 is "D"

Comment: Close. #3 is not correct. Also, are were you referring to me in regards to breaking the rules for #4? If so, what rule did I break?

Comment: Also, I did expect Ruby for #5, not Perl. But you still have it on a list, so I count it.

Comment: @tfitzger is #3 Mary L(eakey) because it will fit the problem, but there are many other possible names..? Also I didn't closely read your statement *sounds alike* since I was rushing to answer :p

Comment: The scientist in question is one who fits with the theme of the words. You are correct that she is female. I should have used the word Mathematician instead of scientist to describe her...

Comment: @tfitzger fixed to Ada Lovelace - having notes that are recognized as the first algorithm intended to be carried out by a machine.